# Spring BindingResult check for errors automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controllers I have everywhere:

```
  if(result.hasErrors()) {
     return "redirect:/foo/bar";
  }
```

Is there a way to automatically redirect to that uri? I am thinking if I can create and annotation to do this, something like:

```
  @HasErrors(redirect="/foo/bar")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a exception mechanism to handle the error assuming like this in your controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkError")
 public ModelAndView process( ) throws Exception {
        User user = new User();

      if (user==null) {
            throw new GlobalExceptionHandler ( );  // throws GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler
        }

       // do something when there isn't error

 }
```

And assuming this the exception ( `CustomeException` class ) that will be thrown  , and when this class thrown you will be redirect to a view , via global exception

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      public  String handleException( ModelMap model) {

        return "/foo/bar";
    }

}
```

or just a custom exception (assuming thrown as `new UserNotFound ()` in your controller )

```
public class UserNotFound extends Exception {
    public UserNotFoundException( ) {
       toView ();
       }

    public String toView (){
     return "/foo/bar";
       }
}
```